# VS2010 Publish Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am having trouble publishing to a Windows 2003 server in VS2010. In the past (with Vs2008) I just had to include the address of the server - now there are some new publish options such as "web deploy" and what not with some settings that I am not aware of. How do I get the publish working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish with web deploy stopped working with me also. My server is local so I use the publish method: "File System"

Then you simply have to type the target of your Windows 2003 Server into the "**Target Location** box.

i.e. \servername\wwwroot\project